# Backup and Restore SQL server files and filegroups

Tags: sql-server, backup, datafile, filegroups

I have a database called Admin. It has only one default filegroup called primary.

```
File group: primary
files in the file group: Admin_data.mdf
```

Now I have taken a full filegroup backup.

```
Backup file name: fg_full.bak
```

Then **created a new ndf in the same file group called sec_file.ndf** and created few tables, inserted 1000 rows on each table.

After an hour took a file backup of my MDF and NDF files

```
MDF backup: Admin_Data.bak
NDF backup: sec_file_ndf.bak
```

File Backup using SSMS
[image]

Here somehow my **sec_file get deleted** so I want to restore latest NDF backup, how can I restore it?

Output of restore headeronly

[image]

```
Restore filelistonly from disk = 'D:\sec_file_ndf.bak'
```

[image]

Comment: After the backup. SQL Server was running during the file backup

Comment: @Randolph West >>> Also, when you say you took a file backup, was SQL Server running when this took place?<<< Sorry, but how could SQL Server take a file backup if it was not running?

Comment: @Randolph West, of course it's possible to do a file backup. Certainly ONLY if SQL Server service IS RUNNING. Because if the service is stopped it just cannot do anything

Comment: @Randolph West, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/back-up-files-and-filegroups-sql-server

Comment: @Randolph - Question updated with snapshot of backup file

Comment: You’ll have to do a filegroup restore, then a file restore, if I recall correctly. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/piecemeal-restores-sql-server

Comment: I did that, First restore the Filegroup backup with norecoery then restored the sec_file_ndf.bak file, the errror is, File 'sec_file' was not backed up in file 1 on device 'D:\sec_file_ndf.bak'. The file cannot be restored from this backup set.

Comment: >>> File 'sec_file' was not backed up in file 1 on device 'D:\sec_file_ndf.bak'<<< Can you post the result of RESTORE HEADERONLY from disk='D:\sec_file_ndf.bak' please

Comment: Ok about your RESTORE HEADERONLY, we see that it's just 1 backup set in this file. What about RESTORE FILELISTONLY? Please post here only relevant columns, not the whole result. I mean, LogicalName and IsPresent colums

Comment: @Bhuvanesh I am curious what do you mean by `sec_file get deleted`? Was it your `sec_file.ndf`?

Answer (score 1):

Query the backup file with

```
RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = 'D:\sec_file_ndf.bak'
```

and

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK= 'D:\sec_file_ndf.bak'
```

...to verify the contents of your `D:\sec_file_ndf.bak` file.

You might have multiple backups in one *.BAK file. If so add the option `FILE = 2` to your RESTORE command to restore your most recent backup of the `*.NDF` file.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your database is in `FULL` recovery model (as you confirmed in comments) it's possible to restore just the second file.

The sequence is this one:

- backup log admin to disk = '...\tailofthelog.trn' with norecovery;
- restore database admin file = 'sec_file' from disk = '...' with
  norecovery;
- restore database admin from disk = '...\tailofthelog.trn' with
     recovery;

**UPDATE**

Here is my repro code:

```
if db_id('test') is not null drop database test;
go

CREATE DATABASE test ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'prime1', 
  FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\test.mdf' , 
  SIZE = 3072KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) 
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'test_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\test_log.ldf' , 
SIZE = 1024KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%);
go

alter database test set recovery FULL;
go

backup database test filegroup = 'PRIMARY' 
to disk = 'Z:\backups\default\test_primaryFG1.bak';
go

alter database test add file
( NAME = N'prime2', 
  FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\test_prime2.ndf' , 
  SIZE = 3072KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB );
go 

-- second connection:
use test;
go  
create table dbo.t(id int);
go

-- first connection:  
backup database test file = 'prime1' 
to disk = 'Z:\backups\default\test_prime1.bak';
go

-- second connection:
create table dbo.t1(id int);
insert into dbo.t1(id) values(1);
go


-- first connection:
backup database test file = 'prime2' 
to disk = 'Z:\backups\default\test_prime2.bak'

-----------------------------------
backup log test 
to disk = 'Z:\backups\default\test_tail.trn' with norecovery;

restore database test file = 'prime2'
from disk = 'Z:\backups\default\test_prime2.bak'
with norecovery;

restore database test
from disk = 'Z:\backups\default\test_tail.trn' with recovery;

-----------------------------------
-- just another restore starting with FD restore as OP did:
restore database test 
from disk = 'Z:\backups\default\test_primaryFG1.bak' with replace, norecovery;

restore database test file = 'prime2' 
from disk = 'Z:\backups\default\test_prime2.bak' with norecovery


restore database test
from disk = 'Z:\backups\default\test_tail.trn' with recovery;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, In my case database, is in FULL recovery mode only, and yes I didn't take any tail backup. So my question is if I took a tail backup then How can I restore the sec_file alone? other files are fine.

Comment: I need time to verify it because in your particular case the file is a part of PRIMARY FG. I'm afraid the minimum unit to be restored in case of PRIMARY FG is the whole group, not just 1 file

Comment: it's just a Testing database. So im ready to run any queries

Comment: ok, I've tested it right now and I'll update my answer

Comment: I also tested your sequence: First restore the Filegroup backup with norecovery then restore the sec_file_ndf.bak with norecovery and finally restore tailofthelog backup with recovery and it also worked. Obviously it took more time but this is a valid sequence. This second restore was done after the first one, so instead of doing tailofthelog backup with norecovery I used restore with REPLACE at the fist restore as I've already got my tailofthelog backup

Comment: Im getting error while restoring the sec_file backup,
  File 'sec_file' was not backed up in file 2 on device 'D:\sec_file_ndf.bak'. The file cannot be restored from this backup set.

Comment: I've already asked about it but you did not respond, I'll copy it here: "Ok about your RESTORE HEADERONLY, we see that it's just 1 backup set in this file. What about RESTORE FILELISTONLY? Please post here only relevant columns, not the whole result. I mean, LogicalName and IsPresent colums"

Comment: Updated in question

Comment: I asked you for TWO columns only, but you still did not show IsPresent column

Comment: Oh ok,

here is the result of LogicalName and IsPresent  ----
Admin_data,0 | sec_file , 1 | Admin_log ,1

Comment: I cannot explain your error, the backup contains the correct file, can you copy+paste file name from the result of restore filelistonly into your restore command to be sure that it is correct?

Comment: If you want I can just update my answer with my code that I executed successfully on my server.

Comment: we can move to chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64291/discussion-between-bhuvanesh-and-sepupic).

Comment: Sure, please update the answer, anyhow its testDB not prouction